# Typescript: How to selectively choose what types are exported?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a component library in Typescript. The API for this library is two named exports: the component, and a helper function to create an object that can be passed into the component as a prop. Simple enough.

So I have an `index.ts` file that I use as the entry point.

```
import Component from './Component';
import { helperFunc } from './helperFunc';

export { helperFunc, Component };
```

Now the component will also import the following function from say `internal.ts`

```
export function foo(bar: string): string { ... }
```

I don't want the types for this file generated. This isn't something the user will use or need. It's internal only.

I only want the types for the exported code, in this case `helperFunc` and `Component` to be be built and distributed, but not types created for anything but those two. It's simply not needed.

Comment: I'm dealing with this challenge, too, and it's looking like I'll have to move non-API types to separate files and use `.npmignore` to blacklist them.

Comment: I never thought of using `.npmignore`, that's a really good shout actually.

Comment: Ideally one could programmatically walk the import tree starting at `dist/index.d.ts` and whitelist those types.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack's `ts-loader`, the option [`onlyCompileBundledFiles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader#onlycompilebundledfiles) looks like what you need.

> The `onlyCompileBundledFiles` option modifies this behavior, loading only those files that are actually bundled by webpack, as well as any `.d.ts` files included by the `tsconfig.json` settings. `.d.ts` files are still included because they may be needed for compilation without being explicitly imported, and therefore not picked up by webpack.

Comment: No, sorry. Using a bundler that uses Rollup down the chain.

Answer (score -1):

You can't keep code out of the def that's being referenced anywhere within the library. Since javascript doesn't really have a concept of private entities, the functions will appear in the build, but won't be importable without climbing the tree of the package.

Comment: I want the `helperFunc` to be in the `.d.ts` file, as it's exported. I don't want internal functions to be in a `.d.ts` file though. I can't use the internal functions if they're in another file if I don't export them.

Comment: Ahh.. I misunderstood.  AFAIK, if you don't export those helper functions in the module, they won't be in the d.ts file.

Comment: Nope, types besides `helperFunc` and `Component` are definitely generated.

Comment: They're being created because they're being used, but are they importable/public?

Comment: Well they can be used just by virtue of being distributed. `import { internalFunction } from 'package/dist/internalFunctionTypedFile';` Just ignoring them is a valid way to deal with the issue. They just pollute the package, even if they are negligible in size.

Comment: Unfortunately (for this question, anyway), that's how it works.

Comment: But by the time this code is distributed the code isn't being referenced anywhere. I bundle everything together. The function that those type definitions are for literally doesn't exist. It's been inlined by that point and is no more. So the types definitions are defining entities that aren't around.